# How to cast curse as aura?

Tags: path-of-exile

[Impresence (physical)](https://www.poewiki.net/wiki/Impresence_(Physical)) causes Vulnerability to have no reservation when cast as aura. How can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's described right in the same wiki that you linked:

> Vulnerability can be turned into an aura by linking it with either
> [Blasphemy Support](https://pathofexile.fandom.com/wiki/Blasphemy_Support) or [Awakened Blasphemy Support](https://pathofexile.fandom.com/wiki/Awakened_Blasphemy_Support)

[See link here](https://pathofexile.fandom.com/wiki/Vulnerability#Skill_functions_and_interactions)

Blasphemy Support turns hex curse gems into auras when supporting them. That usually reserves 35% of maximum mana. With [Impresence](https://www.poewiki.net/wiki/Impresence_(Physical)) equipped, the reservation is 0% (= none).

The easiest way to obtain that gem is by buying it at [Clarissa](https://pathofexile.fandom.com/wiki/Clarissa) in act 3 as any character.